# Port 443 set up SSL on Nginx + Ubuntu + EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl, https

I've tried everything and I searched Google behind some solution, but can not configure SSL (https) in my Nginx server that is within a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on Amazon EC2.
My website works perfectly on port 80 with HTTP, but I would leave it safer adopting HTTPS.

Considerations:

1. whenever I try to access it via `https://` gives the error: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
2. the command `curl -v https://www.mywebsite.com/` returns: 
   `curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.mywebsite.com port 443: Connection timed out`
3. the command `nc -vz localhost 443` returns: `Connection to localhost 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!`
4. the command `nc -vz myserverIP 443` returns:
   nc: connect to *myserverIP* port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
5. TCP 443 port for HTTPS are open to anywhere on Security Groups (Amazon ec2 firewall) on inbound and outbound.
6. `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN:

   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1244/proftpd: (acce
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1130/sshd
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5633/nginx
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5633/nginx
   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1130/sshd
   tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5633/nginx
   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5633/nginx

**Nginx configurations:**

1. nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/ebSaqabh
2. `ssl.conf` (called by include of `conf.d` on `nginx.conf`): 
   http://pastebin.com/FzVAtjGz
3. `sites-available/default`:

   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
       charset utf-8;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;

   ```
   server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
   #return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
   #rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mywebsite.com$1 permanent;
   location / {
       #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
           }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
   }
   #include /etc/nginx/common/w3tc.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/common/wordpress-seo-plugin-support.conf;
   ```

   }

I do not know what else to do to resolve this. Someone could help me? Do you have something wrong in my configuration of Nginx? Or need to change anything else in the Amazon?

Comment: Any Firewall enabled ?

Comment: only the firewall of the Amazon, but the door 443 as I mentioned earlier is open.

Comment: The pastebins are offline, can you repaste them?

Comment: Your PasteBin links are broken.  Please add the content here.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my... :(
The Ubuntu Firewall (UFW) was activated (noob). I added `ufw allow 443/tcp` and now it's all right.
sorry for the post. But who is riding a webserver with nginx and php-fpm can enjoy the above settings are all correct and my website is now functioning normally also with https.